# Parsing XML files to LogStash

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following logstash conf file:

```
input {  
file 
{
    path => "C:\Dashboard\Elmah\*.xml"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "error"
    codec => multiline 
    {
        pattern => "^<\?error .*\>"
        negate => true
        what => "previous"
    }
    sincedb_path => "C:\Dashboard\Elmah"
  }
}

filter 
{
    xml 
    {
        source => "error"
        xpath => 
        [
            "/error/@errorId", "ErrorId",
            "/error/@type", "Type",
            "/error/@message", "Message",
            "/error/@time", "Time",
            "/error/@user", "User"
        ]
        store_xml => true
    }
}

output 
{
    elasticsearch 
    { 
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "stock"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout 
    {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

When I run bin/logstash -f agent.conf I do not get an error but no data gets inserted into Elasticsearch. An example of the file is: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oni2zhorsdtz6p/error-2015-06-26203423Z-3026bd43-07d6-44d6-a6cf-6d27b28a607e.xml?dl=0

How do I get Logstash to read in a collection of external xml files?

***LogStash Debug Output:***

```
Please see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7g1154uvf9fr1f/outputlog2.txt?dl=0
```

Comment: What do you get from your stdout{} output?

Comment: @AlainCollins: I have added the information you requested

Comment: I meant your logstash stdout (you have an output stanza that references it).

Comment: @AlainCollins: I  am not sure I understand "LogStash stdout". I have documented the "LogStash command output" above. Are they not the same? I am a newbie in the LogStash, ElasticSearch arena.

Comment: You have a "stdout" output in your logstash config.  This will print every event that makes it through logstash to your stdout.  Where this goes is up to you and/or your init script, but it will show you what the document looks like before it goes to elasticsearch and can be helpful for debugging.

Comment: It seems that LogStash is logging the "Failed to install template: Connection refused: connect" error when it is trying to process the xml files. Please see the output log when I run the logstash command with the --debug parameter. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7g1154uvf9fr1f/outputlog2.txt?dl=0
Any inputs on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use the file input here -- I've only seen it used to monitor files for changes, not to monitor for new files. Unless your XML files are updated, I don't think it will do anything. Remember that logstash is watching for new log lines typically.

Most people write tools like the following to process whole files in batch:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-river-wikipedia

https://github.com/andrewvc/wikiparse

https://github.com/elastic/stream2es

Those tools, especially the last one, seem much closer to your use case.

Comment: If you're trying to run it (repeatedly) for testing, either remove the sincedb file or set the path to /dev/null.

Comment: @Martin: The Stream2es does not seem to support parsing xml files.

Comment: @AlainCollins: No files were created in the C:\Dashboard\Elmah folder. I changed the "sincedb_path" to /dev/null and ran LogStash and ElasticSearch again but I got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to process files containing one xml document on each line using the following logstash configuration. Hope this help!

```
input {  
    file {
        path => "/tmp/logstash/test.log"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {
    xml {
        source => "message"
            force_array => false
            xpath => [  
            "/Event/@timestamp", "time",
            "/Event/user[1]/id[1]/text()", "user",
            "/Event/user[1]/ip[1]/text()[1]", "ip",
            "/Event/@eventType", "eventType",
            "/Event/transactionDuration/text()", "trxDuration",
            ]
            store_xml => true
    }
}

output 
{
    stdout{
        codec => line {     
            format => "%{[time]}    %{[user]}   %{[eventType]}  %{[trxDuration]}"
        }
    }
}
```